# 'Method Range of object _Global failed'

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen a few posts on this problem. I know what's causing it but I'm trying to figure a way to stop it from appearing.

What it is there is one excel file called Main which I have to keep open and it updates automatically using every 20 mins using:

```
    Application.OnTime
```

In the VBA formula there is a call for

```
Loc = Range("location").Value
```

So if I have another excel file open I get the range error when it auto-updates.

Is there something I can put in before to check that the value isn't right and ignore that one error? I've tried a few things and looked around but nothing really works.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't show much code, but I'd guess that your unqualified `Range()` call is the problem: that will refer to whatever happens to be the ActiveSheet (unless it's in a sheet code module).  If you fix that it should resolve your problem.

Comment: I know what the problem is, I'm trying to find a way to block or check for an empty value while in another file. Basically I have Book1.xlsm open auto-updating then open Book2.xlsm the value is looking for location from Book1.xlsm that isn't declares in Book2.xlsm. So while I have Book2.xlsm I don't want the error to display and I don't want to turn off all errors.

Answer (score 0):

> I know what the problem is, I'm trying to find a way to block or check for an empty value while in another file.... Demas 5 mins ago

I agree with Tim here. If you can fully qualify your range then do that. Else read on :)

Is this what you want?

```
Dim rng As Range

'
'~~> Rest of the code
'

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Range("location")
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Loc = Range("location").Value
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End If
```

Comment: I appreciate this though I've tried things like this. The On Error doesn't work and I've tried different way to qualify the value; declaring the workbook name in the value, a function for making sure this workbook was active and a few others.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Do you get any error messages? Posting from phone so may take some time to reply back